# raspberrypi - on boot not running my infinite python script?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, boot, bash

I have a Python script, which needs to run 24/7 to use GPIO high/low. So on boot i wanted it to run as below. But it never works to run python script on other hand it does create /tmp/test file?

How do i make it work?

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local 
#!/bin/sh -e
echo 'hello world works?' > /tmp/test

echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value

echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value

/home/pi/pypy.py > /var/log/pypy.py.log 2>&1 &
exit 0
```

**EDIT:**

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.13

$ ls /home/pi/pypy.py 
/home/pi/pypy.py
```

**pypy.py:**

```
import urllib2
import os
import time
from time import sleep

while True:
  time.sleep(2)

  contents = urllib2.urlopen("https://xx.xxx.com/test/status?command=get").read()
  if contents in ('reboot', 'reboots'):
    os.system('echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value')
    os.system('echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value')
```

**ERROR:**

```
$ cat /var/log/pypy.py.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pypy.py", line 11, in <module>
    contents = urllib2.urlopen("https://xxxxxxx").read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

Comment: How do you know the script doesn't run?  What is it meant to do?

Comment: You're not doing any error handling. You need to do something like `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/pypy.py > /var/log/pypy.py.log 2>&1 &` in order to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

it **Works**

**Step 1:**

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local 
#!/bin/sh -e

# Test if rc.local even executing?
echo 'hello world works?' > /tmp/test

# Setup the GPIP
echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value

# Python infinite loop run 
# with ERROR handler
/home/pi/pypy.py > /var/log/pypy.py.log 2>&1 &

exit 0
```

**Step 2:**  pypy.py

```
$ chmod +x /home/pi/pypy.py
$ cat /home/pi/pypy.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import os
import time
from time import sleep

while True:
  time.sleep(2)

  try: 
    contents = urllib2.urlopen("https://site/command").read()
    if contents in ('reboot', 'reboots'):
      os.system('echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value')
      os.system('echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value')
      sleep(0.5)
      os.system('echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value')
      os.system('echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value')

  except:
    print "ERROR - so what continue you idiot?"


# 
# - Before Network is ready Python was executed
# - So repeat the execute by ignoring the failure
#
```